# Get all items withing a bounding box in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, geojson

I've a problem with a query matching items inside a BoundingBox.
I've read in the mongo [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/box/) a lot without success about `$box` and `$geoWithin` but can't figure out why the item which is inside the queried box is not resulting.

Here an example from defined Schema over an Item inside and the Query to get it out

The schemadefinition looks like this and it's validation is working.

```
/**
 * Media location values (Point, LineString, Polygon)
 * @property location
 * @type {Object}
 */
 location:{
            "type":Object,
            "index":"2dsphere"
 },
```

One item inside looks like this (which is expected as a result of the query):

```
{
    "_account": "52796da308d618090b000001",
    "_id": "5280d9c6592dce2d36000001",
    "location": {
        "coordinates": [
            50.109230555555555,
            8.757613888888889
        ],
        "type": "Point"
    },
    "name": "Büro",
    "preview": "/img/thumbs/13869-2gqv8n.JPG",
    "type": "image/jpeg",
    "added": "2013-11-11T13:21:10.951Z",
    "latlng": [ ],
    "shares": [ ],
    "shared": false,
    "tags": [ ]
}
```

The query to fetch the item looks like

```
{
    // tried also "location.coordinates" without luck
    "location": {
        " $geoWithin": {
            "$box": [
                [
                    49.99825021043669,
                    8.543586730957031
                ],
                [
                    50.139285461134996,
                    8.996772766113281
                ]
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Whats wrong here to get always en empty array as result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see one thing that is wrong here. Shouldnt `" $geoWithin"` be `"$geoWithin"` ??

Comment: Do you know what is required to get also linestrings and polygons inside the result?